# Multiple lines of VBA

Tags: vba

Trying to use VBA to enter break time in a spreadsheet.  1st Break, Lunch, 2nd Break.   I have three sets of code in vba but am only able to get the 1st break code to work  other two do not give a result.  I have attached the VBA Code.  I am new to VBA as you can see.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet1_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Break 1
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 15
xTimeColumn = 6
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
        For Each xRg In xDPRg
            If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet2_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Lunch Break
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 16
xTimeColumn = 8
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
        For Each xRg In xDPRg
            If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            End If
        Next
    End If
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet3_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Break 2
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 17
xTimeColumn = 10
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
        For Each xRg In xDPRg
            If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

There are three columns where time is entered, and three columns that a dropdown has the reference to run formula.

Comment: `Worksheet#_Change` will not work.  There is only `Worksheet_Change`  You need to combine the three into one and use block `If` statements to decide which part should be run.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I am so new at this I am confused as to how to combine.  Could you give me a little more help on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Scott Craner’s advice, you could do a nested `IF` solution – but with all your current`IF` `Else` `End If` conditions in your existing code, I think it would become too difficult to maintain.  Another possibility is to use a `Select Case` approach, and the code below uses that instead.  I tested it and it seems to give you what you want.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo GetOut
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim xCellColumn As Integer, xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow As Integer, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg As Range, xRg As Range

If Not Intersect(Range("O:Q"), Target) Is Nothing Then
xCellColumn = Target.Column

Select Case xCellColumn

    Case Is = 15
    
        xTimeColumn = 6
        xRow = Target.Row
        xCol = Target.Column
        If Target.Text <> "" Then
            If xCol = xCellColumn Then
               Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
                For Each xRg In xDPRg
                    If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                        Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    
    Case Is = 16
        
        xTimeColumn = 8
        xRow = Target.Row
        xCol = Target.Column
        If Target.Text <> "" Then
            If xCol = xCellColumn Then
               Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
                For Each xRg In xDPRg
                    If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                        Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
                    End If
                Next
            End If
         End If
    
    Case Is = 17
        
        xTimeColumn = 10
        xRow = Target.Row
        xCol = Target.Column
        If Target.Text <> "" Then
            If xCol = xCellColumn Then
               Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
                For Each xRg In xDPRg
                    If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                        Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If

End Select

End If

Continue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
GetOut:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Continue
End Sub
```